# Is it possible to access clearcase from lab network?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

we are having clearcase in our organization production network. There is another separate network which is having limitted ports are opened. The users in production network will not be there in lab network.

Is it possible to open few ports and access clearcase from the lab network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your support IT and network admins, but yes, you can open ports if you know which ones are important for ClearCase.

See "[About Firewalls and ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117638)"

> IBM Rational ClearCase is known to operate correctly through firewalls in internal networks if the following conditions are met:
>
> - Port 371 (UDP and TCP) is passed through to any/all ClearCase server hosts from the allowed hosts.
> - All ports over 1024 (UDP and TCP) are open from the allowed ClearCase client hosts to needed ClearCase server hosts.
> - On Windows with McAfee Antivirus (access protection), also open port 6666 (IRC). `Cleartool.exe` may use that port to acquire a license.
>     If you do not open that port, the user command will fail with `error: Unable to contact albd_server on host`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible to open the ports on your lab network and able to use the clearcase from there 
The general ports which are for clearcase is port 371 UDP and TCP which is used for the Clearcase server and 1024 UDP and TCp which is used for Clearcase client